# Function not updating the global variable

Tags: python

I have the following function

```
 class calculation()
       
       x=3
    
       def calculateOO(y):
          global x
          x=3*y
     
       calculateOO(2)
            
       print(x)
```

The answer is 3, not 6. The function does not have an effect.

What is wrong with the function?

Comment: The answer is `6` not `3`. Are you sure the indentation is correct?

Comment: At least with correct indentation, the code works as expected. The current indentation in your post is not valid at all, but the problem on your side seems to be also indentation-related. We can help you understand what's going on if you [edit] the post to reflect the exact indentation in your code, otherwise, the problem cannot be reproduced and the question cannot be answered.

Comment: You have code in the scope of the class definition. It seems you're still learning OOP because what you've done there is ... unusual. Do you really want to know what your code does or would you prefer to learn why your code is not what OOP is about?

Comment: Short explanation: When you do `global x` and `x=3*y` you define `x` on a global level. But your `print(x)` is not on global level, so it accesses the `x` from the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

With proper indentation:

```
x=3
def calculateOO(y):
    global x
    x=3*y

calculateOO(2)
print(x)   # 6
```

Comment: I use this in class outside class work properly but inside a class still the same not working

Comment: @TarekMesto  that should not change a thing. Please post your class code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
x=3

def calculateOO(y):
    global x
    x=3*y
    return  print((3*y),x)

calculateOO(2)
```

Hope you find this solution helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused with global variables, return statements, and functions. play around with this and read my comments inline:

```
x=3
def calculateOO(y):
    global x
    x=3*y

def calculateXX(z):
    y=3*z
    return y

print(calculateOO(2))
#prints None, as the function has no return statement
print(x)
#prints 6, as we set x to be global in the calculateOO() function above

print(calculateXX(2))
#prints 6, as we return the value inside the function
print(y)
#causes an error, as we did not set a global y
```